# Doctrine autoloading error

Tags: php, symfony, ant, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm getting a weird error when running phpunit tests using ant.
Tests are functional tests in Symfony framework, and they run fine if directly invoked on the same machine (using the same user).
When I try to run a build using ant, the autoloader fails to load Doctrine annotations. I'm not sure if other autoloadings are working, maybe the annotation one is the first encountered.
Errors are like the following:

> Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error]
>   The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column" in property
>   AppBundle\Entity\User::$id does not exist, or could not be
>   auto-loaded.

Here is the relevant part of build.xml (nothing much to see):

> ```
> <target name="phpunit-xdebug" description="PHPUnit tests with coverage">
>     <exec executable="${workspace}/bin/phpunit" failonerror="true">
>         <arg value="-c" />
>         <arg path="${configdir}/phpunit.xml" />
>         <arg value="--log-junit" />
>         <arg path="${builddir}/logs/junit.xml" />
>     </exec>
> </target>
> ```

Edit. Following is phpuni.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/appendixes.configuration.html --> 
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    colors                      = "false"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/var/bootstrap.php.cache"
 >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="project Test Suite">
            <directory>/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/app" />
        <ini name="xdebug.coverage_enable" value="1" />
    </php>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/build/coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/src/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="\DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitStaticDbConnectionListener" file="/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/vendor/dama/doctrine-test-bundle/src/DAMA/DoctrineTestBundle/PHPUnit/PHPUnitStaticDbConnectionListener.php" />
    </listeners> 
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Post your `AppBundle\Entity\User` Entity code please.

Comment: does your phpunit config point to a valid bootstrap file? phpunit.xml would be helpful.

Comment: edited original post and added phpunit.xml